# cannot get attached property value

Tags: wpf, mvvm, attached-properties

Hi I hope I can find some help here...

I am creating a WPF application using prism and MVVM.

I am trying to create an attached property which i found [here](http://thebrainyprofessionals.com/2013/04/12/attached-properties-in-wpf/).

in my ViewModel I get the focused Element by

```
var control = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
```

then I do

```
string value = ExtraTextBehaviourObject.GetExtraText(control as UIElement);
```

but the value returned is always null... Can anyone point me to the right direction???

**UPDATE**

```
public class ExtraTextBehaviourObject : DependencyObject
    {
        //Declare the dependency property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ExtraTextProperty;

        static ExtraTextBehaviourObject()
        {
            //register it as attached property
            ExtraTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ExtraText", typeof(string),
                                                                    typeof(ExtraTextBehaviourObject));
        }

        //static function for setting the text
        public static void SetExtraText(UIElement uiElement, string value)
        {
            if (uiElement != null)
            {
                uiElement.SetValue(ExtraTextProperty, value);
            }
        }

        //static function for getting the text
        public static string GetExtraText(UIElement uiElement)
        {
            if (uiElement != null)
            {
                return (string)uiElement.GetValue(ExtraTextProperty);
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Set code in XAML

```
<dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding Path=Customer.Comments, Mode=TwoWay}" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Behaviors:ExtraTextBehaviourObject.ExtraText="HelloExtraText"
                                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

Comment: You should perhaps also post the implementation of your property.

Comment: thanks for you reply... I've just updated the "set" code

Comment: Hmm, why is your class deriving from `DependencyObject`? Since you're using `UIElement.GetValue()` and `UIElement.SetValue(...)`, you don't need that.

Comment: SetExtraText never gets called... this is probably the issue... but why?

Comment: When a dependency property is set in XAML, WPF does not call the C# setter method. So the fact that SetExtraText isn't called doesn't mean that the property value isn't set. Anyway, are you really sure that the element returned by `Keyboard.FocusedElement` is the one that you expect?

Comment: i am getting a System.Windows.Controls.TextBox instead of a TextEdit with the expected value in it's Text Property

Comment: Sounds like you get a TextBox that is part of the `dxe:TextEdit` control. You'll have to traverse the element tree upwards until you get that control. No idea if this is a good approach for something to be done in a view model.

Comment: thanks for your replies... I'll try this and I will come back

Comment: what do you want to achieve? and btw check this to get some information about dependency properties: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html . your code for the viewmodel looks not very MVVM... so either you call the false object a viewmodel or your put code in your viewmodel wich should not belong to it (UIElement stuff)

Comment: what i want to achieve it to set an attached property to a text box with that will be able to hold some text data. now I figured out what the problem was thanks to Clemens replies. I have to traverse the  element tree upwards until I get that control TextEdit Control... And yes, I will move the code from the VM as this code does not belong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't getting the right control when I used Keyboard.FocusedElement. This may be a devexpress thing as I use their controls. So traversing the element tree upwards until I get that control solved my problem... Thank you Clemens!

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional idea: Instead of traversing the tree by hand yourself, you could let WPF do that for you. Flag your attached property with `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits` now the value can be retrieved by all children of the initial control where you set the attached property.
For example

```
<Grid MyService.MyProperty="True">
   <TextBox .../>


var txt = aSender as TextBox;
var val = MyService.GetMyProperty(txt);
```

With `Inherits` `GetMyProperty` will return `true`, because it "inherits" the value from his parent Grid, without inherit of course the value would be `false` (not null, because its a value type).

`DataContext` for example is also an inherited dependency property.